# Partial form submission

Tags: php, html

I have a table that is also a form, I need to be able to select a check box and when I submit the form only submit the corresponding text box on the same row I dont know any ajax currently but if that is the ONLY way to do it then so be it but preferably I would like a non ajax solution, here is a screen shot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Post the entire form. On the receiving page implement the logic to process only those rows where the checkbox is flagged.

Comment: Post the html code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you don't want to use AJAX**:

1. As @LelioFaieta said, you can process the checked rows in your backend page
2. You can use pure javascript to put the checked rows values as hidden values in the form and the user will submit the form with hidden values...

   Something like that:

```js
function toggleValue(arg){
    var exist = document.getElementById(arg+'checked');

    if(exist == null){
        var val = document.getElementById(arg);

        var hidden = document.createElement('input');
        hidden.type = 'hidden';
        hidden.value = val.value;
        hidden.id = arg+'checked';

        document.getElementById('form2').appendChild(hidden);
    }else{
        exist.remove();
    }
}

function updateVal(arg){
    var element = document.getElementById(arg+'checked');

    if(element != null){
        var val = document.getElementById(arg);
        element.value = val.value;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='text1' onchange='updateVal("text1")'>
<input type='checkbox' onclick='toggleValue("text1")'>

<form id='form2' action='backend.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

Honestly i think that this is an ugly solution and i suggest you to use AJAX